# Падает Qt Gui приложение в Windows при закрытии. В линуксе не падает

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

[image: Стек вызовов]

Не понятно как искать причину ошибки. Она открывается при открытии в главном окне одного виджета, но там слишком много кода, не понятно где искать ошибку. Я подумал, что дело в двойном удалении мб, закомментировал все delete и ошибка осталась.

Comment: Вангану, что с гуйнёй общаешься напрямую из стороннего потока…

Comment: Ну типа того, я из dll посылаю команды через SendMessage главному окну.

Comment: гм... в winapi я не так хорошо разбираюсь, так что не скажу, на сколько это криминально... но я бы в эту сторону копнул… также я бы попробовал поставить брейк на `QFontCache::clear()` и посмотреть из каких других мест он вызывается…

Comment: как предположение: в windows в отличие от линукс нельзя динамическую память получать в dll а отдавать в exe и наоборот

Comment: @Pavel Gridin , можете по подробнее объяснить на что обратить внимание. О каких кейсах идёт речь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128719/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример. сейчас это гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: Приложение слишком большое, поэтому пример привавести затруднительно, я просто ищу людей, который падали на таком же стеке вызовов и решили данную проблему. Просто какие-нибудь варианты.